# How to get the user name by not primary key field in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have two tables as the following

```
USERS
--------------
id   name
--------------
1    Joe
2    Adam
--------------


TASKS
--------------------------------------------------------
id   user_id   assigned_to   content     
--------------------------------------------------------
1       1               1     bla_bla_a
1       1               2     bla_bla_b
--------------------------------------------------------
```

### CONTROLLER

```
$tasks = Task::all();
return view('list', compact('tasks'));
```

### VIEW

```
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Creator</th>
    <th>ASSIGNED TO</th>
    <th>CONTENT</th>
</tr>

@foreach($tasks as $task)
<tr>
    {{ $task->id }}
    {{ $task->user->name }}
    {{ $task->assigend_to }}  // what sould i write here to get the user name.
    {{ $task->content }}
</tr>
@endforeach
```

My question is: what should i do to get the user name which task is assigned to in the view?
Regards

Comment: Can you show us your Task model?

Answer (score 0):

Use One To One relationship. [Read Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

In **Task.php** Model add this relation

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now fetch like `$task->user()->name;` in View

If you have this relationship already in Model then just eager load the User with Task by following :

Changes in Controller -

```
$tasks = Task::with('user')->get();
```